# SpacyBert/SpacyCake cannot perform reduction function max on tensor

Tags: python, spacy, huggingface-transformers

I've installed *SpacyBert* and *SpacyCake* to extract keyword phrases from a corpus of text. I've checked all the dependencies and have everything installed but I am getting the below error. Any ideas?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 449, in __call__ doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {})) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacycake/__init__.py", line 105, in __call__ second_part = torch.matmul( RuntimeError: cannot perform reduction function max on tensor with no elements because the operation does not have an identity
```

I have the correct language model downloaded so not sure what could be causing the issue. The models I have tested with:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md") and
nlp = spacy.load("en")
```

Spacy is working fine because I can perform other NLP tasks but it's just when I try using:

```
cake = bake(nlp, from_pretrained='bert-base-cased', top_k=3)
nlp.add_pipe(cake, last=True)

doc = nlp("This is a test but obviously you need to place a bigger document here to extract meaningful keyphrases")
print(doc._.extracted_phrases)
```

Comment: Please explain in detail which language model you are using or downloaded? because there are several language models and spacy is working perfectly as far as I have tested until now.

Comment: Here you are using wrong model. I think, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: According to the pip install instructions I'm not. https://pypi.org/project/spacycake/ I have checked with 'en' and en_core_web_md separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using wrong model. This model is for other purpose.
Huggingface transformer model is pretrained `"bert-base-uncased"`

Here you are using wrong model.

[See this](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg-2.2.0)

```
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg
```

Comment: Thanks. Downloading now. I'll let you know how it goes.